# Get Jetty to gracefully shutdown ServletContextListener

Tags: jetty

I have a web application that is deployed in Jetty 11.0.2.  I have a ServletContextListener registered in web.xml,

```
<listener>
    <description>A listener that starts and stops all managed services based on the lifecycle of the web application context.</description>
    <display-name>Service Management Listener</display-name>
    <listener-class>com.bb.base.webservices.servlets.services.ServiceManagementListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

When jetty starts and my web application is deployed, the `contextInitialized(...)` method is being called, however when I shut down jetty using `kill -s TERM ${JETTY_PID}` the `contextDestroyed(...)` method is not being called.  In my server.ini file, I have enabled graceful shutdown with,

```
jetty.server.stopAtShutdown=true
jetty.server.stopTimeout=15000
```

When jetty shuts down I am seeing it do the clean shutdown.  I see;

```
2021-05-01 05:19:16.605:INFO :oejs.Server:JettyShutdownThread: Stopped Server@7a6d7e92{STOPPING}[11.0.2,sto=15000]
2021-05-01 05:19:16.606:INFO :oejs.Server:JettyShutdownThread: Shutdown Server@7a6d7e92{STOPPING}[11.0.2,sto=15000]
2021-05-01 05:19:16.630:INFO :oejs.AbstractConnector:JettyShutdownThread: Stopped ServerConnector@60db1c0e{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8443}
2021-05-01 05:19:16.631:INFO :oejs.AbstractConnector:JettyShutdownThread: Stopped ServerConnector@3b5fad2d{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2021-05-01 05:19:16.631:INFO :oejsh.ContextHandler:JettyShutdownThread: Stopped o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@2dd80673{/.well-known,null,STOPPED}
2021-05-01 05:19:17.093:INFO :oejsh.ContextHandler:JettyShutdownThread: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@c5dc4a2{Fermenation,/,null,STOPPED}{/opt/fermenation/live/jettyCfg/code/services-3.4.4.war}
```

The last line being the shutdown of my web app context.  However, my listener is never called.

This logic used to work in earlier versions of jetty. I am pretty sure it worked in jetty 9.4, however I unfortunately don't have the log files anymore so I can not see it for certain.  May have been an earlier version of jetty when I implemented this to begin with which is the only time I know beyond a doubt it worked.

I would appreciate any suggestions anyone has.  Can't figure out why this has stopped working.

Shutdown logic...  You never know it is broken until it is a serious problem that it is broken.

Comment: File an issue at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Comment: Done.  Thanks.  Was not sure if there was more configuration I needed to do on the new version of Jetty or whether this was potentially a bug.  https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/6237